# How long does it take for the AWS API describeInstances query to complete for 1000000 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Good day, I am using the AWS API and I was wondering if I ran the describInstances query with no filters for an account with 100000 instances how long would it take for that API call to complete. I am using a free tier account so I cannot really launch 1000000 instances and test myself,but if anyone has run this call with a large number of instances and got an idea for the time I could calculate an approximation. Thank you very much for your time

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a program question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help, I have measured on 3 different accounts with:

```
[foo@foo ~]$ time aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-west-1 > result.txt
```

These are the results:

```
No of instances  | time in seconds
              7  |          0.772
            128  |          2.506
            467  |          3.603
```

Excel `TREND` function extrapolates this to 553 seconds for 100k instances, so this may give you a very rough estimate.

Comment: Thank you so much that estimation is all I needed too know